# Angular 2 Event emitters vs Subject

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 what is the difference between Event Emitter and Subject for announcing an event? It seems like event emitters are less complicated to declare....Which way is preferred by Angular 2?

```
dataRefreshEvent = new EventEmitter();

private companyDataAnnouncedSource = new Subject();
companyDataAnnouncedSource$ = this.companyDataAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
```

Comment: After fully learning Rxjs now I realise that so much more can be done with EventEmitters.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

There is not much difference. `EventEmitter` extends `Subject`.

The Angular2 team stressed the fact though, that `EventEmitter` should not be used for anything else then `@Output()`s in components and directives.

The Angular team [has stated](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3038-eventemitter-is-an-rxjs-observable-stream-in-angular-2-beta-6.htm#comments_47949) that they may change the underlying implementation of `EventEmitter` and break user code that uses `EventEmitter` for something it wasn't intended for. That's the main difference.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I'll stick with Subject then although it seems alot of extra steps to achieve the same outcome.....much like with alot with angular 2

Comment: Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: It was mentioned by Misko in comments to Github issues. I don't have a link.

Comment: Couldn't find the source, but the [EventEmitter documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) says "Use by directives and components to emit custom Events," which seems to support this answer.

Comment: `EventEmitter` is just a very simple abstraction that allows the Angular team to replace `Subject` by some custom implementation without breaking all existing code, but currently it doesn't look like this will be needed at all though.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2018? (angular 5/6)

Comment: @Jessycormier looks the same to me https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2x/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L59

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you for the source, I wish the docs would have these details as well https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter Thanks again!

Comment: @Jessycormier I haven't followed Angular closely since a while but that `EventEmitter` is a `Subject` is an implementation detail you shouldn't need to care about. You shouldn't use it for anything else then `@Output()` and its Subject properties shouldn't matter. At the beginning of Angular times there were plans to eventually replace it with some custom implementation - not sure this plans still exist. So it's understandable the docs don't go into details here. It is rather something the RxJS docs should cover.

Comment: Why not just use Subject instead of EventEmitter everywhere even for @Output()?

Comment: Because then you get no guarantee that it will still work after the next update.

Comment: would have been easier to understand Angular if we used "emit" for all instead of "next" :'( It's why Angular is so complicated (crying again)

Answer (score 52):

Also `EventEmitter` gets cleaned up automatically unlike custom `Subjects` that you need to unsubscribe to in the `onDestroy` lifecycle hook.

Comment: This is the most important part of EventEmitter and a reason it exists

Comment: Why would you say this?
Look here:  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/183757daa28e575bd9ffb8ae6c31ebee7ff45443/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L142

Without going into greater detail, anything that is an observable will be tracked and unsubscribed.

Comment: this answer is not true, please read https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emitter-vs-subject sample.

Comment: It's not true that "EventEmitter gets cleaned up automatically". I tested it myself, and it does NOT "clean up automatically". If you don't unsubscribe from it manually, you'll have a memory leak. THE BOTH HAVE TO BE UNSUBSCRIBED MANUALLY! The answer has to be deleted.

Comment: Any subscriptions added to an `@Output` through a template (`(myOutput)=".."`) are automatically cleaned up. Any subscriptions added in user code are not. EventEmitter and Subject are exactly the same in this regard, so I think this answer is wrong.

Comment: 47 upvotes for an answer that's wrong.  There is nothing in the docs about lifecycle differences: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Answer (score 13):

`EventEmitter` and `Subjects` serve the same purpose - to notify about an event to an observer.

But `EventEmitter` should only be used to notify an event from the child to the parent i.e., it should only be used with `@Output()`.

To notify about an event across different components, `Subjects` should be preferred. Subjects emit the value from one component and any other component can subscribe to it and it'll get notified.

Answer (score 5):

EventEmitter by default is synchronous, whereas Subject is not. 
You can pass a flag to EventEmitter to make it asynchronous.

Comment: not sure you are right
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpcmue
both are sync

Comment: For anybody who comes across this later, Subjects are synchronous. EventEmitter is synchronous by default, but can be passed a flag in the constructor for it to run Asynchronous.

Comment: If interested in running subscription logic asynchronously; https://stackoverflow.com/a/45223232/9947918
(Would of edited last comment, but wouldn't let me.)

Answer (score 0):

`EventEmitter` should be used for establishing **Parent-Child** relationship with `@Output` decorators, whereas `Subject` should be used in case of **Sibling** relationship; certainly inside a service file (`@Injectable`).