# Angular 4 : How to use await/async within subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I can honestly say await/async in angular is really a great stuff, it reduces a lot of braces, improves readability and prevent a lot of human error. However, one thing puzzles me a lot. how can I use await/async inside subscribe.

let's say

```
 @Injectable()
export class TableCom extends BaseCom {
  public subject = new Subject<any>();

}
```

TableCom is a provider serves as a communicator between a signalr component and a page component.

so inside the page component constructor, it is using the observable subject to receive new data from signalr component as shown below.

```
constructor(protected nav: NavController,
        protected db: Storage,
        protected alert: AlertController,
        protected order: OrderData,
        protected translate: TranslateService,
        public navParams: NavParams,
        public toastCtrl: ToastController,
        private table_data: TableData,
        private load: LoadingController,
        private http: Http,
        private com_table: TableCom

    )
    {
        super(nav, db, alert, order, translate, undefined, false);
        this.previous_page = navParams.get('previous_page');
        this.subscribe_table = this.com_table.Receive().subscribe(res =>
        {
            await this.SaveTableAsync(res.data);
            this.ReadTableAsync();
        });
    }
```

the issue is that the this.ReadTableAsync() basically has to wait this.SaveTableAsync to be finished before starting. await can be achieved here ? thank you in advance !!

Comment: async/await is used where promises are expected, does `SaveTableAsync` returnsa promise? and `await` can only be used inside `async function() {...}`

Comment: yes. SaveTableAsync wrap up ionic storage which is promise based.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need the `async` keyword to mark the function as "async":

```
this.subscribe_table = this.com_table.Receive().subscribe(async res => {
    await this.SaveTableAsync(res.data);
    this.ReadTableAsync();
});
```

Comment: Can you expand on this, what if the method is a bind? For example: `.subscribe(this.SaveTableAsync(res.data).bind(this))`, would you put async before the first `this`?

Comment: Since `await` itself is not interested in `this` but only in the return value of the method/function call (which will in most cases where `await` is used return a `Promise`), I can see no rule that could restrict the location of `this`. Can you elaborate on your doubts?

Comment: That pretty well answered it. My goal was to determine if a different approach was needed in the case where `.bind(this)` is used. In practice, I had to do something that looked like: `.subscribe(await this.someMethod(parameter).bind(this))`. Just wanted to make sure it worked with the answer you gave above, since the syntax is a bit different.

Comment: In case of error and completed is it the same way?
is the below correct?
`this.subscribe_table = this.com_table.Receive().subscribe(
         async res =>       {
                                 await this.SaveTableAsync(res.data);
                                 this.ReadTableAsync();
       },
         async (error) =>  {
        await this.errorhandling(error);
       },
         async () =>      {
        await this.completedhandling();
       },);
`

Answer (score 0):

Where is the implementation of SaveTableAsync() because this method needs to return a promise to be awaited.

Since the subscribe() method takes an arrow function, you can simply add the async keyword before the definition i.e:

```
subscribe(async res => {
    await this.SaveTableAsync(res.data);
    this.ReadTableAsync();
});
```

If you the `ReadTableAsync()` method returns an Observable, you first need to use the `toPromise()` method to return a [promise from the observable before you can asynchronously await](https://www.techiediaries.com/javascript-async-await-tutorial/) for it