# Vue Method calls

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vue method which gets a json response with axios.get and also i have another method which depends on the first method. Right now I am setting a timeout for the second method. Is there any way to do this without setting timeout ?

```
displayDetails(){

        this.showDataTable();
        setTimeout(this.addHeaders,5000)


 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying `showDataTable` uses `axios.get`? Then make `showDataTable` return promise and use `then` method of it:

```javascript
displayDetails () {
  this.showDataTable()
    .then(data => this.addHeaders(data))
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the values are not getting reflected

Comment: Then you need to post more details, but this is how you should do it. Make sure `showDataTable` returns Promise like this: `return axios.get(...)`

Comment: Of course, because you didn't return Promise, do like I said in previous comment.

Comment: You can also use async/await behavior 
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223198/angular-4-how-to-use-await-async-within-subscribe

Comment: Yeah finally made it to work. Thanks @dfsq . Really appreciate the help