# I'm getting delayed Ionic native http response in iPhone only

Tags: ios, http, ionic3, http-post

I'm having an issue in getting the response from API with Ionic native HTTP. Is there anyone knows how to solve this issue in iPhone. I have been spent hours searching for the solution. It works normally on other devices and browsers. Any help would be appreciated. Do you guys know the reason behind this?

```
this.httpGet.post(url,data,{}).then(data=>{
 console.log("data",JSON.stringify(data));
 let json_data = JSON.parse(data.data); 
 resolve(json_data)
}, (err) => {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
 resolve("error");
});
```

Comment: You need to use async await to mark the function as ["async"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45223232/5354124)

Comment: Even though I used async for this, the problem would be the same. I think you don't understand my problem.
I'm getting the response even if it took time, that is not my problem.
**The issue is the time it takes to get the response in iPhones than a normal request in any other device**

Answer (score 0):

Run your application in simulator
go to developer option select you application 
[image]

and click on network to track your all requests 
[image]

hope you will find what is wrong with requests.