# Return Observable from http Post

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I am working on a sample app, where I have a Login Component, which calls authentication service. The service in turns makes an Http call, and based on the response of the call, I need to do something.

In the service, I am using http Post along with subscribe to do stuff when my user is able to login, however, I want my component function to consume this response from my manipulation and proceed accordingly.

Below is the code:
**Login Component:**

```
this.authService.login(this.userName, this.password)
```

**Authentication Service**

```
 return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login',{
  "username": userName,
  "password": password
}).subscribe(data => {
   //some stuff
  return true;
  }, () => return false;
})
```

I want my LoginComponent to wait till it receives true or false from the service.

One way to do this will be just to return the http call back to component and write whole logic there, but that is not what I am looking forward to. I was hoping if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Don't subscribe in service. Subscribe in component.

Comment: Usually services don't execute logic. The common thing is to return the Subscription from the service and subscribe in the component. I know you sayd that is not what you're looking for. But a workaround could be to use a variable in the service that is setted to true or false when the subscribtion in the service return something. In the component do a setTimetout that every n milliseconds check if the variable is not undefined. When it has a value, you know the service has finished its job. But meh, I don't think is a good way.

Comment: ^*return the Observable from the service*

Comment: Op can you be more specific about what is the _stuff_ that you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can write

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
```

and

```
return new Observable((subscriber) => {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', {
        userName,
        password,
    }).subscribe(data => {
        //some stuff
        subscriber.next(true);
    }, () => subscriber.error();
});
```

Comment: How does this answer has 2 upvotes? wrapping an observable in another for no reason? srsly?

Comment: Please read the question, ```//some stuff``` is the reason @Jota.Toledo

Comment: For side effects you could simply use `tap`, and for transforming the response into a boolean value `map`. OP needs to be more specific.

Comment: Obviously, there'll be more solutions to this issue. I just give him one

Comment: Awesome... Neat and clean solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the observable into your login component and subscribe there. Then you can do what you want if the request succeded

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22246768)

Comment: Oh really? Other answers provided the same idea

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()

export class AuthService {
  constructor (private client:HttpClient) { }

  logIn(userName:string, password:string):Observable<boolean> {
    return (this.client.post('myUrl', {'userName': userName,'pwd':password}).pipe(
      map(resp => {
        // perform logic
        const allowed:boolean = resp['authenticated'];
        return allowed;
      })
    ));
  }

}
```

Component

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private authSvc:AuthService) { }
  authObservable$:Observable<boolean>;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authObservable$ = this.authSvc.login('myUser', 'myPwd');

    // can use authObservable$ in template with async pipe or subscribe

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `of` operator:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
return this.http.post('...url..', payload).subscribe(data => {
   //some stuff
  return of(true);
  }, () => return of(false);
})
```

Answer (score -2):

I think **Async and Await** is what you are looking for,
[How To Use Async and Await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223198/angular-4-how-to-use-await-async-within-subscribe)