# How can I call method which is created/located in a parent component while I'm in a child component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on Angular app, its basically small app which is displaying spots for cars,
cars could be on different regions (like in garage, outside of garage)..

And when I click on spot it's changing colour to red, like it's taken, but I can not see it until I close window and come back again.

Here are 2 components,

one `cars-spot-list` is parent component, and `car-spot` itself is child component as it's part of list.

So what I want to do, is when I click on car spot I'm updating my database as that spot is taken and I would like to call my method again `getCarSpotsByArea`() but it's located in `parent-component`,
so my question is how can I call parent method from a child component?

I might move it to a `service`, but I would like to avoid that.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

My code:

When I click on **child** component `car-spot` for example Spot 1, this happened:

```
 onClick(carSpot: CarSpot) {
        this._carSpotService.changeCarSpotState(carSpot).subscribe(
          // Successful responses call the first callback.
          () => {
           // CALL AGAIN SOMEHOW METHOD FROM A PARENT TO REFRESH MY VIEW 
           // for example: getCarSpotsByArea(carSpot.areaId);
          },
          (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err.error instanceof Error) {
              console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
            } else {
              console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
            }
          }
        );
      };
    }
```

**Parent** component:  `car-spot-list` component

```
    getCarSpotsByArea(areaId: string) {
    this._carSpotService.getCarSpotsByAreaId(areaId)
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.carSpots = data;
      },
      // Errors will call this callback instead:
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
          console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${JSON.stringify(err.error)}`);
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: You can use `Subject` to do that. Here's a simple stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vts7zd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts

Comment: Don't listen to @JacopoSciampi, that is not a good practice. Listen to [the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) instead.

Comment: Well, that's not a good reasons. According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238549/angular-2-event-emitters-vs-subject it's just another approach. Next time be more specific.

Comment: @trichetriche can you give me an example how could I call a method from a parent component ? So I can discuss it here with other people

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I didn't say it was bad, I meant it was not the best practice. if you look at the doc, your solution is there. It's just not suited for this particular case.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro I gave you the documentation. Read it, you'll know what to do.

Comment: @trichetriche I'm almost done, I will post my example in a 5 mins so we can comment it togger if it's good one?

Comment: Sure ! Notify me when you have posted it

Comment: @trichetriche check for my solution please, didn't know it's so simple, if it's right approach it's cool, but I might solve it also with shared services? like okay on success now let's call method from a service getCarSpotsByArea but it means I should move my method to a service.. and that's more job than to do it like this :=) and I just want to know is this right approach and is it allright solution? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I think the best solution is to move it to a service. What if you need this in another spot as well? The **right** approach is to move it into a service.

Comment: @trichetriche is correct. You should not use a service, you just bubble the event up from the child to the parent.

Comment: @Roxy the first one is bad practice (it tightly couples your components, so you can't reuse them), the second one is useless (you can just use `#p` for the same effect without exportAs). Shared services are great for unrelated components, for related components outputs are better. Bottom line is, all work great, you just have to find the one that suits you. And congratulations on finding those, you're part of the 1% that actually learn by reading further than one page of doc :)

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks mate, so basically my solution as I posted in answer is pretty fine? :)

Comment: I would say it's the best one :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did:

In my child component I've created a property which will emit value that I need:

```
@Output() onUpdateCarSpot = new EventEmitter<string>();


onClick(carSpot: CarSpot) {
    this._carSpotService.changeCarSpotState(carSpot).subscribe(
      // Successful responses call the first callback.
      () => {
       // Here is the place where I needed to call parent method so here
       // on success callback I've emitted value
          this.onUpdateCarSpot(carSpot.areaId);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
        } else {
          console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
        }
      }
    );
  };
}
```

And in parent component `car-spot-list.component.html` I did next ( is part of ) :

```
<car-spot (onUpdateCarSpot)="getCarSpotsByArea($event)"></car-spot>
```

I've added an `(onUpdateCarSpot)` which is acctually name of my `Output` event emitter from my Child component, and I've simply told:

Okay, when I emit something (it's on callback in a child component), call a method called `getCarSpotsByArea` and I've passed/emitted `areaId` because my parent's method `getCarSpotsByArea` accepts and `areaId` as a argument and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to EventEmitter as mentioned above, there are 2 other ways to call parent component from child components

1) Inject parent component into child component

```
export class ChildComponent  {
  constructor(private parent: ParentComponent) {

  } 

  callParentMethod() {
    this.parent.methodHandler();
  }
}
```

2) If you have control over ParentComponent, you can use exportAs:

```
@Component({
  ...
  exportAs: 'parent'
})
export class ParentComponent  {
  ...
}

export class ChildComponent  {
  @Input() handler: Function;
  ... 
  callParentMethod() {
    this.handler();
  }
}
```

In Html, you can reference it as:

```
<parent #p="parent">
  <child [handler]="p.methodHandler"></child>
</parent>
```